# How to enable Kerberos delegation from SQL Server to DFS File Share

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, dfs, delegation

I am trying to enable my MSSQL database users to BULK INSERT / OPENROWSET() a CSV file that is stored on our DFS/cifs/smb network shares.

### Initial Setup

I have the MSSQL service set to run as a domain user account, `EXAMPLE\svc_mssql`, and have added that user to a security group that has read access to the relevant DFS share (eg. `\\example.org\myshare\data\path\to\mydata.csv`). This allows users connecting to the database via SQL Authentication to read the files on the share successfully as there's no Kerberos double-hop issues present:

```sql
C:\Temp>sqlcmd -N -S %DB_HOSTNAME% -U %DB_USERNAME% -P %DB_PASSWORD%
1> SELECT
2>   CAST(CONNECTIONPROPERTY('auth_scheme') AS nvarchar(10)) AS auth_type,
3>   COUNT(*) AS NumLines
4> FROM OPENROWSET(
5>    BULK '\\example.org\myshare\data\path\to\mydata.csv'
6>  , FORMATFILE = '\\example.org\myshare\data\path\to\mydata.fmt'
7> ) AS f;
8> GO
auth_type  NumLines
---------- -----------
SQL                 73

(1 rows affected)
```

### Kerberos

I have [manually registered the SPNs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections?view=sql-server-2016#Manual) for MSSQLSvc in AD and they do show up properly on that service account:

```
C:\Temp>setspn -Q MSSQLSvc/DBSERVER.example.org
Checking domain DC=example,DC=org
CN=svc_mssql,OU=ServiceAccounts,DC=example,DC=org
        MSSQLSvc/DBSERVER.example.org
        MSSQLSvc/DBSERVER.example.org:1433

Existing SPN found!
```

This allows me to successfully connect to SQL Server using kerberos authentication:

```sql
C:\Temp>sqlcmd -N -S %DB_HOSTNAME% -E
1> SELECT CAST(CONNECTIONPROPERTY('auth_scheme') AS nvarchar(10)) AS auth_type;
2> GO
auth_type
----------
KERBEROS

(1 rows affected)
```

### Unconstrained Delegation

If I set the service account to be trusted for delegation (ie. unconstrained delegation) like so:

```
PS C:\Temp> Get-ADUser svc_mssql -Properties TrustedForDelegation,TrustedToAuthForDelegation `
>>   | Select-Object Name,TrustedForDelegation,TrustedToAuthForDelegation

Name      TrustedForDelegation TrustedToAuthForDelegation
----      -------------------- --------------------------
svc_mssql                 True                      False
```

Then everything works fine and dandy:

```sql
C:\Temp>sqlcmd -N -S %DB_HOSTNAME% -E
1> SELECT
2>   CAST(CONNECTIONPROPERTY('auth_scheme') AS nvarchar(10)) AS auth_type,
3>   COUNT(*) AS NumLines
4> FROM OPENROWSET(
5>    BULK '\\example.org\myshare\data\path\to\mydata.csv'
6>  , FORMATFILE = '\\example.org\myshare\data\path\to\mydata.fmt'
7> ) AS f;
8> GO
auth_type  NumLines
---------- -----------
KERBEROS            73

(1 rows affected)
```

### Packet Trace - Unconstrained Delegation

After much trial and error and trying to surmise/guess what is needed for constrained delegation, I installed wireshark on the database server and grabbed a packet trace from the working unconstrained setup. I'm not a networking expert, but this is what (I think) I see in that trace:

1. TGS-REQ/REP for `cifs/DOMAINCONTROLLER01.example.org`
2. TGS-REQ/REP for `krbtgt/EXAMPLE.ORG`
3. SMB tree connect request for `\\DOMAINCONTROLLER01.example.org\IPC$`
4. SMB Ioctl FSCTL_DFS_GET_REFERRALS for `\example.org\myshare`
5. TGS-REQ/REP for `cifs/FILESERVER01`
6. SMB tree connect request for `\\FILESERVER01\IPC$`
7. SMB Ioctl FSCTL_DFS_GET_REFERRALS for `\FILESERVER01\myshare`
8. TGS-REQ/REP for `cifs/FILESERVER02`
9. SMB tree connect request for `\\FILESERVER02\IPC$`
10. SMB Ioctl FSCTL_DFS_GET_REFERRALS for `\FILESERVER01\myshare\data`
11. TGS-REQ/REP for `cifs/NASCLUSTER01`
12. SMB tree connect request for `\\NASCLUSTER01\Data`
13. More SMB traffic to actually read the files...

I can see the need to proxy/impersonate to the two `cifs/FILESERVER` SPNs since they are the underlying nodes for the DFS namespace. After some research, I can also understand the `cifs/NASCLUSTER` SPN, as that is where the file servers are actually storing the data.

The first two requests though, I do not fully understand. I'm guessing the first one `cifs/DOMAINCONTROLLER01.example.org` is so that SQL Server can look up the nodes in DFS namespace that is hosting the requested fileshare. If so, I guess I need the service account to be allowed to delegate to `cifs` on ALL domain controllers, right?

That leaves the `krbtgt/EXAMPLE.ORG`. I don't understand what this is doing. Why is it getting a TGT? Am I misreading the trace? I see it is a tgs-req with a msg-type of `krb-tgs-req (12)` -- same as the others. Is this protocol transition? If yes, why is that happening in this scenario?

## Update

So, I tried (again) to set up `svc_mssql` with constrained delegation for the following SPNs:

1. cifs/FILESERVER01
2. cifs/FILESERVER02
3. cifs/NASCLUSTER
4. cifs/DOMAINCONTROLLER01

Looking at the packet trace, I see `krb-tgs-req (12)` for `cifs/FILESERVER01` which gets a `krb-error (30)` with an error-code of `eRR-BADOPTION (13)`. The original `krb-tgs-req` had `kdc-options` = `40830000`, which wireshark decodes as:

```
kdc-options: 40830000
    0... .... = reserved: False
    .1.. .... = forwardable: True
    ..0. .... = forwarded: False
    ...0 .... = proxiable: False
    .... 0... = proxy: False
    .... .0.. = allow-postdate: False
    .... ..0. = postdated: False
    .... ...0 = unused7: False
    1... .... = renewable: True
    .0.. .... = unused9: False
    ..0. .... = unused10: False
    ...0 .... = opt-hardware-auth: False
    .... 0... = unused12: False
    .... .0.. = unused13: False
    .... ..1. = constrained-delegation: True
    .... ...1 = canonicalize: True
    0... .... = request-anonymous: False
    .0.. .... = unused17: False
    ..0. .... = unused18: False
    ...0 .... = unused19: False
    .... 0... = unused20: False
    .... .0.. = unused21: False
    .... ..0. = unused22: False
    .... ...0 = unused23: False
    0... .... = unused24: False
    .0.. .... = unused25: False
    ..0. .... = disable-transited-check: False
    ...0 .... = renewable-ok: False
    .... 0... = enc-tkt-in-skey: False
    .... .0.. = unused29: False
    .... ..0. = renew: False
    .... ...0 = validate: False
```

I compared the options to the packets in the unconstrained delegation and the only difference is the `constrained-delegation` bit is flipped -- as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Help!?!?!?

Comment: Does the odd TGS-REQ include any unusual preauth data (tgs-req.padata)?

Comment: @user1686 What would be unusual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that during our initial troubleshooting we enabled kerberos delegation for the `DBSERVER$` computer account in AD. This apparently caused the system to go down a different path looking for RBCD, which we are not doing.

Bottom line, resetting the machine account to no delegation and adding constrained delegation on the service account for the two fileservers and the NAS cluster resolved the issue completely.